# Next.js: How to create multiple dynamic pages coming from different types of API?

Tags: next.js

This is my first experience with Next.js. I am trying to create a dynamic route from the data coming from `server`. 
I do convert the `id` to `string`  but have the same `error`.

```
Server Error
Error: A required parameter (articleid) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths for /article/[articleid]
```

I tried something similar with the data from `web api` it works fine but not for the data that I fetch from `server`.  Can't figure out what I am missing.
Also why `error` message is pointing out `server error` in the first line?

Here is the component the `error` is coming from: pages/article/[articleid]/index.js

```
export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const res = await fetch(`${server}/api/article/${context.params.id}`);
  const article = await res.json();
  return {
    props: {
      article,
    },
  };
};

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(`${server}/api/article/`);

  const articles = await res.json();
  const ids = articles.map((article) => article.id);

  const paths = ids.map((id) => ({ params: { id: id.toString() } }));

  return {
    fallback: "blocking",
    paths: paths,
  };
};
```

`pages/api/article/[id].js file

```
import { articles } from "../../../data";

export default function handler({ query: { id } }, res) {
  const filteredData = articles.filter((article) => article.id === id);

  if (filteredData.length > 0) {
    res.status(200).json(filteredData[0]);
  } else {
    res.status(404).json({ message: `article with id of ${id} is not found` });
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I found out that my problem is definitely not from the code provided above.
Actually in my app I have another dynamic page where I fetch the data from another `web api`, which works fine. Changing the `url`s I found out that now `web api` dynamic page is throwing the same error. I assume the problem is that how I defined the `paths`, , [articleid] I mean. 
Here is my components structure 
[image]

The problem is with `pages/article/[articleid].
Here is how I am linking to the specific item

```
 <Link href="/article/[articleid]" as={`/article/${article.id}`}>
      <a className={styles.container}>
        <h1>{article.title} &rarr;</h1>
        <p>{article.body}</p>
      </a>
    </Link>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You need to fetch props every time you use a dynamic page.

Comment: Hi @JoelHager thanks for the response. 
Could you explain, please, how I can fetch props every time I use dynamic page? 
Does it mean, that I should use getServerSideProps instead of getStaticProps?

Comment: Server side props is for fetching from a backend server, and static paths is run build-time to determine paths for static site generation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I made it work changing the dynamic route `id name` in brackets, in my case `[articleid]`, to just `[id]` and it worked fine. Image below. 
But honestly, I didn't understand why the previous keyword ([articleid]) in brackets was not working. 
I also tried another keywords inside the brackets for dynamic route like [article] and nothing worked except [id]. 
I didn't find anything related in Next.js docs about that.
I'd welcome any explanations why only [id] worked.
[image]

Comment: It's expecting whatever you put in brackets to be the prop passed.